# Collection of $5$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that any $3$ are Linearly Independent

Tags: vector-spaces

I am looking for a collection of $5$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that any $3$ are linearly independent. What I tried to do at first is set up a collection of linear equations like this:
$$c_1M_1 + c_2M_2 + c_3M_3 \ne 0$$
     $$c_1M_1 + c_2M_2 + c_4M_4 \ne 0$$
     $$c_1M_1 + c_2M_2 + c_5M_5 \ne 0$$
     $$c_2M_2 + c_3M_3 + c_4M_4 \ne 0$$
     $$\ldots$$

and so on for any combination, which is retrospectively obviously incorrect. So I think I need $5$ vectors, each with $3$ elements that are all linearly independent. But this doesn't seem possible to me. Can anyone shed light on what I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

$$(1,0,0)$$
$$(0,1,0)$$
$$(0,0,1)$$
$$(1,1,1)$$
$$(1,2,3)$$